# Call pdflatex with a stream

Tags: pdftex, compiling

When creating LaTeX-driven reports, I would like to skip writing LaTeX sources to the disk prior to compilation and cleaning up afterwards. Can a stream be sent to `pdflatex` somehow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

without specifing an output name you get with

```
cat test.tex | pdflatex &>/dev/null && rm texput.log texput.aux
```

the output file `texput.pdf`

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but it seems to me that `test.tex` is written to a filesystem; it is not a stream.

Comment: that is a demonstration how a stream can go to `pdflatex`. In this case it comes from `cat` and in your case "I don't know ..."